# DockerでJenkinsを立ち上げシェルを実行するとエラーになる

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

後述の記事を参考に、
DockerでJenkinsを立ち上げ`echo 'Hello world'`を実行してみたのですが、
以下のエラーが出てしまいます。

プラグインはUIからSuggested Pluginsでインストールしており、
plugins.txtは使っていません。

Javaにクラスが無いと言うのはわかるのですが、
具体的な解決方法がわかりません。
解決方法がわかる方、ご教授いただけますでしょうか。

---

参考記事：
https://dev.classmethod.jp/tool/jenkins/jenkins-on-docker/

エラー内容：

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test
FATAL: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jenkins/scm/RunWithSCM
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.defineClassFromData(AntClassLoader.java:1139)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy$AntClassLoader2.defineClassFromData(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:878)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.getClassFromStream(AntClassLoader.java:1310)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1366)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob$SCMListenerImpl.onCheckout(WorkflowJob.java:653)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jenkins.scm.RunWithSCM
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1376)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1326)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1079)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

実際に利用したDockerfileを教えて下さい。
ベースイメージは参考記事の通り `jenkinsci/jenkins:2.11` を利用しているのでしょうか。
plugin.txtは利用していないとありますが、具体的にどのような違いがあるのかを示して下さい。

この `jenkinsci/jenkins` はすでに[メンテナンスが終了](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/)しており、
`jenkins/jenkins` という[新しいイメージを利用すること](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/)が推奨されています。
また、2.11というバージョンも古く、インストールしたプラグインと整合性が取れていないため
上記のようなエラーが発生したのではないかと思います。

ベースイメージとして最新安定版の `jenkins/jenkins:lts` などを試してみて下さい。
最新安定版のイメージを利用しても解決しない場合は、
具体的にどのようにJenkinsプロジェクトを作成して `echo 'Hello World'`を実行したのかも
記述するとコメントできると思います。

Comment: >ベースイメージは参考記事の通り jenkinsci/jenkins:2.11 を利用しているのでしょうか。
おっしゃる通り`jenkinsci/jenkins:2.11`を使用していました。
メンテナンスが終了しているとは知らず…ltsで再度立ち上げ直した所、エラーが出ることなくジョブが実行できました。
非常に助かりました、本当にありがとうございました。